# Does it make sense to use generic parameters to select which service implementation will be injected?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a class called `ReportWorkflow<TReport>` that calls some objects to generate a report of a specific type, the object are always called in the same sequence and the only true difference is the actual implementation of each object.

The constructor of this class looks like:

```
public ReportWorkflow(... , IFileNameProvider<TReport> fileNameProvider)
```

The `ReportWorkflow<TReport>` is constructed using dependency injection.
There are multiple `ReportWorkflow<TReport>` registered at the same time in the DI Container, like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IReportWorkflow, ReportWorkflow<HrReport>();
services.AddSingleton<IReportWorkflow, ReportWorkflow<AccountingReport>();
//More ReportWorkflows registrations...
```

To make sure that I get the correct file name provider for every `ReportWorkflow<TReport>` I've added the generic parameter `TReport` to the interface `IFileNameProvider<TReport>` but this interface never uses the generic parameter and it is only there to 'mark' and distinguish an implementation from another.

The interface definition is as follows

```
public interface IFileNameProvider<TReport> {
    string GetFileName();
}
```

An implementation simply fills the generic parameter with the report type and it will be registered like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFileNameProvider<HrReport>, HrFileNameProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IFileNameProvider<AccountingReport>, AccountingFileNameProvider>();
```

This will ensure that when I will try to resolve `ReportWorkflow<HrReport>` I will get `HrFileNameProvider` and when I will try to resolve `ReportWorkflow<AccountingReport>` I will get `AccountingFileNameProvider`.

The 'type markers' `HrReport` or `AccountingReport` are actual classes used and returned by other objects and do contain some information.

Does it make sense to have interfaces that use generic parameters just as a sort of 'marker' to distinguish one implementation from another? And if yes, does this pattern have a name?

Comment: This seems to negate the use of abstracting behind an interface entirely, since you're still coupled to the implementing type and are still using different compile-time types in your code instead of a single abstract type.  I'm not seeing any benefit of this over just using the implementations directly.

Comment: Seems pretty opinion-based, doesn´t it? There may be conditions where marker-interfaces or even marker-arguments might be okay. However we can´t know.

Comment: @David That's true, I didn't come to me that I was just 'avoiding' to name the implementation while still being tied to it, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, you may just have reinvented [phantom types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type) ;)

While it's a (quaint) thing in Haskell and other statically typed functional programming languages, the question here also implies that it may not be the most [idiomatic](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/08/03/idiomatic-or-idiosyncratic) design to apply to C#.

All that said, it seems to me that this is a workaround to make a DI Container work with the design. When a DI Container is in the way, it'd be worthwhile to consider whether it actually adds value, or if it's rather a liability.

Consider throwing away the container and instead relying on [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di). That could make everything simpler, and might also make the use of phantom types redundant.

Comment: I agree, it is a workaround to make the DI Container behave and it is also defeating the purpose of using abstractions over concretions. Thank you for the answer and for the very interesting articles linked, definetly worth one or two reads.